# Gradle not picking right appcompat-v7:22.2.1

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I am facing a strange issue, i installed latest appcompat-v7:23.0.0
Where as i got to know i must not need it but i need to go with appcompat-v7:22.2.1 or appcompat-v7:22.0.0

I updated my gradle as per my needs but it always pickup appcompat-v7:23.0.0 which is not required, any one guide me how can i resolve this issue?

[image: error message]
[image: Appcompat-v7 installed]
[image: Gradle]

Comment: set buildToolsVersion `22.2.1` . let me feedback .

Comment: Why that `com.google.android.gms:play-services` has `+` ? try to use that like the doc with specific version.: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'` -> https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup i didn't see `+` is usable or not, weird. and the first image's errors comes from 23 api which you don't set it to the dependecies i guess.

Comment: i really appreciate your help, my android studio was too old 1.2.0 now i updated to 2.0 and these issues resolved, it will help others as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

you are using the latest version `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'` which has a dependency with support libraries **v23**.

**You have to compile with API 23.**

Change this line:

```
 compileSdkVersion 23
```

If you don't want to use the api23 you can use a specific version like as

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
```

**In general is not a good practice the use of** `+` in your dependencies because you can't replicate the build in the future with the same libraries and you don't know which version you are using.

Also **you can use api23 with Httpclient**.
Just use:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

More [info here.](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client)

The `useLibrary` requires the gradle plugin 1.3.0 (`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'`) or higher.

Comment: after using useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' i am getting following error:  Gradle dsl method not found (uselibrary)

Comment: @UMAR which version of gradle plugin are you using? It requires the 1.3.0 or higher. For example : classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'

Comment: one last error and i am done: after adding legacy it resolved rest of apache imports related issues but it is unable to resolved import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

Comment: @UMAR Now move ahead .

Answer (score 1):

> AppCompat (aka ActionBarCompat) started out as a backport of the
>   Android 4.0 ActionBar API for devices running on Gingerbread,
>   providing a common API layer on top of the backported implementation
>   and the framework implementation. AppCompat v21 delivers an API and
>   feature-set that is up-to-date with Android 5.0

You can use

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.1'
```

**Finally**

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1' // You can set  buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
```

**Advice**

You should use

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0' // or 8.4.0
```

**`Good Approach :`**  **Use latest Version** .

> you need to download the latest support repository  from internal SDK
>   manager of Android Studio or from the stand alone SDK manager. Then
>   you can add compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0' // or 8.4.0
}
```

**Edit**

You can use this classpath

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
```

Then **Clean-Rebuild-Restart-Sync** your project . Hope this helps .

Comment: I dont want to use 23 appcompat because i am using apache httpclient etc.. and they are not supported in this, that's why i need to stick with 22